# Django Ajax jquery 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, ajax

could someone help me find a way to make mine ajax request work?
I found some of the same questions on this site but didn't solve them.
I want to Ajax the process to show modal

I'm using the latest Django version. I have never used ajax, so I don't really know what I'm doing. Please help
What should I specify for the URL?
Url to display Ajax?
Url to process Ajax?

```
app.urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('test/', include('test.urls')),    
]
```

```
test/urls.py

urlpatterns = [
    path('rex/', IndexView.as_view(), name='rex_index'),
]
```

```
test/templates/test/rex.html

{% extends 'main/layout.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<!--modal-->
<script>

$(function(){
$('#edit_foo').on('click', function () {
    console.log("test")
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/rex_index/',
        data: {
            html: '<form id="form_foo"><textarea></textarea><input type="submit"></input></form>',
            delay: 1,
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#foo_modal').find('.modal-body').html(data);
            $('#foo_modal').modal('show');
        },
    });
});
});

// Handle submit.  Here we return an error regardless of the
// input given:
$("#foo_modal").on('submit', '#form_foo', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/rex_index/',
        data: {
            html: '<form id="form_foo_2"><span class="error">You must write something silly here:</span><textarea></textarea><input type="submit"></input></form>',
            delay: 0,
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#foo_modal').find('.modal-body').html(data);
        },
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

// Handle second submit.  Here we close the modal.
// In a real application you can use the status to determine
// which action to take (success or redisplay the form).
$("#foo_modal").on('submit', '#form_foo_2', function (e) {
    alert('Thanks for writing something silly.  Closing modal');
    $('#foo_modal').modal('hide');
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

</script>

<button type='button' id='edit_foo' class='buttons'>push me</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="foo_modal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">Server Side Modal Popup Demo</div>
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


{% endblock %}
```

```
views.py
***There is no description related to modal in view**


class IndexView(LoginRequiredMixin,FilterView):
    model = Order
    filterset_class = OrderFilter
    template_name = 'test/rex.html'
    
    queryset = Order.objects.all()     

    strict = False

    paginate_by = 10

    def get(self, request, **kwargs):        
        if request.GET:
            print("実行")
            request.session['query'] = request.GET
            print("query",request.session['query'])
        else:
            request.GET = request.GET.copy()
            if 'query' in request.session.keys():
                for key in request.session['query'].keys():
                    request.GET[key] = request.session['query'][key]

        return super().get(request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: There are many issues the url in ajax should be `test/rex` not `rex_index` and you have to send form data as serialised form data and in views you have define a post function as you are calling post method

Comment: You should be able to find a django ajax tutorial somewhere to at least get you started. Coming here before you have thoroughly researched how it should work is not the best place to start. This is not a "how to" tutorial service

Comment: @charlietfl He is hardcoding the form data that is not good it should be in a template with csrf token tag and then he can send serialized form data. He also has to send csrf token otherwise it won't work.